# Babel minify creates empty file on production

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm playing with babel and webpack. I try to transpile my js script but i got a empty js file as output on production.

i tried the babeljs.io page and when i minify i got a error
https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=true&browsers=IE%20%3E%3D%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwBQEpEG8BQjEBOAplCAUsogFSICMADANw4C-QA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=true&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=babili%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.5&externalPlugins=

There is also a Bug for this.
https://github.com/babel/website/issues/1868

What can i do to transpile & minify a js file with webpack & babel

i've tried different versions of babel, different presets and settings

Here my package.json

```
{
  "name": "cookie",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build:dev": "webpack -d --profile --progress",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production -p",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
...
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

(i'm using the preset-env) preset in my .babelrc)

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'bundle.min.css': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/index.scss'),
    ],
    'bundle.js': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/index.js')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
  }
};
```

if i run the `npm run build:dev` script, my file will be compiled. 
But on `npm run build` i get a empty js file in my dist folder without a error message. 
It seems that the babel minfier is breaking the file.

I expect a transpiled & minified js file.